# Unable to receive email to an external email address through Salesforce

Tags: email

I am trying to send an email to a contact through Send an Email option in Activity History section of Contact page. But the contact is not getting any emails in his gmail account. I have attached the screenshot of that page.

[image: Activity History]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Access Level for Email Deliverability:
`Administer>Email Administration>Deliverability`.

Change `Access Level` to `All Email`.

Comment: I did that. Still not receiving email.